# Netbeans - editor colors and fonts

Tags: netbeans, fonts

I'm playing with my editor color schema. I just can't find one element/category to set color for it.

```
<div style="font-family: arial" /> ...
```

What I'm looking for is element/category which describes "**font-family**" element in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select from the menu Tools / Options / Fonts & Colors / Syntax.
Here select Language: HTML.
And "font-family" is in the "Parameter Value" category.

Comment: unfortunately it is not this value, I'm using **monokai theme** :/ and still color is not changed ...

Comment: Here! I did before and after screenshots: before [color change](http://screencast.com/t/kLyD22xq) after [color change](http://screencast.com/t/jvfOYXoTaL)